# Unable to clone sempre from github

Tags: git, macos, github, terminal, clone

Having trouble cloning sempre from github repository. Everytime I write command for cloning from Terminal, I get the following:

```
    $ git clone https://github.com/percyliang/sempre
    Cloning into 'sempre'...
    error: Could not resolve host: (nil); nodename nor servname provided, or not known while accessing https://github.com/percyliang/sempre/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
    fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Comment: Works just fine for me. It was probably a temporary connectivity problem.

Comment: I tried a lot, but still the same message. Anything that I need to configure before cloning.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clone Sempre (or for that fact any github project) because of proxy issues. Try using internet without any proxy.